# Two google analytics tracking Ids for a single android app

Tags: android, google-analytics

I've an android app which is linked with google analytics.

- In my google-service.json there are two clients with two different
  tracking ids (eg:- UA-12345-1 and UA-12345-2).
- But in the source code I've included only one of them (UA-12345-1).
- I've two different properties created in the google analytics web
  page for each trcaking id.
- And each property displays different statistics.

I'm confused, am I doing anything wrong here? which analytics property should I refer to get the correct statistics?

Answer (score 1):

if I understand you well , you need track your app with two tracking key eg: UA-12345-1 , UA-12345-2

in your application class you can refer to many tracker by my method `getTracker` as you pass `trackerId` attribute (in my case it type of enum class called TrackerName ) and return tracker which you can use it to send specific data to it

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    // property id
    private static final String Property_ID = "UA-12345-1";
    public static int GENERAL_TRACKER = 0;

    public enum TrackerName {
        APP_TRACKER, // tracker used only in this app
        GLOBAL_TRACKER, // tracker used by all the apps from a company . eg: roll-up tracking.
        ECOMMERCE_TRACKER, // tracker used by all ecommerce transactions from a company .
    }

    public HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker> mTrackers = new HashMap<>();

    public synchronized Tracker getTracker(TrackerName trackerId) {
        if (!mTrackers.containsKey(trackerId)) {
            GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
            Tracker tracker = (trackerId == TrackerName.APP_TRACKER)?analytics.newTracker(Property_ID)
                    : (trackerId == TrackerName.GLOBAL_TRACKER) ? analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker)
                    : analytics.newTracker(R.xml.ecommerce_tracker);
            mTrackers.put(trackerId , tracker);
        }
        return  mTrackers.get(trackerId);
    }

}
```

> But how can I pass different property ID ?

here is the answer create xml file **res --> xml** with following attribute as we refer it with `R.xml.ecommerce_tracker`

***ecommerce_tracke.xml***

```
<!-- Replace placeholder ID with your tracking ID -->
<string name="ga_trackingId">UA-12345-2</string> // it could be the same 

<bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>
<bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>

<item name="ga_dispatchPeriod" format="integer" type="integer">120</item>

<bool name="ga_anonymizeIp">true</bool>
<bool name="ga_dryRun">false</bool>

<!-- Percentage of events to include in reports -->
<string name="ga_sampleFrequency">100.0</string>

<!-- How long a session exists before giving up -->
<integer name="ga_sessionTimeout">-1</integer>

<string name="YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME">MainActivity</string>
```

> Summery

if you have different tracking id and you want track each one separately , you could achieve that by create different conf files in xml with different property id here the tracker will be changed in `getTracker` method.